# play2 framework @Required field issue

Tags: playframework

I have two methods: login and signup, both of them are using 'User' class which contains userName, email and password. I set all three fields as @Required. It works fine for signup since all three fields are required. Here is the question: I only want to use userName and password to login, but it will give me an error when calling bindFromRequest() method. Is there a way other than remove the @Required annotation for email field or creating two seperated 'User' class for login and signup ?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, one way would be to remove the `@Required` annotation for the email field.
A second way would be to create a separate `User` class for both actions.
A third way would be to use dynamic forms, like that:

```
public Result hello() {
    DynamicForm requestData = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
    String username = requestData.get("username");
    String password = requestData.get("password");
    // now do something with the data we got...
    return ok("Hello " + username);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is pointed by **Anton** - *manual* fetching the fields with `DynamicForm`.

Second is creating additional class like `LoginForm`, which contains only fields and annotations required by logn process and then using it like `Form<LoginForm> ...` instead of `Form<User> ...`

Third option is creating custom `Required` annotation which is context-sensitive, anyway most probbaly previous (second) solution will be easier to implement.